# Using stack to make file/directory tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, stack, filetree

I need to return or print a file/directory tree using stack data structure. For example:

```
Folder1
    Folder1.1
        File1.1.1
    Folder1.2
Folder2
    File2.1
    File2.2
...
```

My code so far:

```
public static void filetree(File mainfolder, int indent){

    Stack<String> filesanddirectories = new Stack<>();

        for (File file : mainfolder.listFiles()){
            if (file.isDirectory()){
                filesanddirectories.push(file.getName());
                filetree(file, 0);
            }
            else if (file.isFile()){
                filesanddirectories.push(file.getName());
            }
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < filesanddirectories.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(filesanddirectories.pop());
    }
}
```

This code prints folders and files but with no indention, backwards and not exactly in the right order.

Could someone explain the logic of how it should work?

EDIT: Found a solution using recursion and stack (although stack seems to be unnecessary)

Comment: To get the indenting working you need to add something to the `indent` value every time you recurse - something like `filetree(file, 0);` -> `filetree(file, indent + 4);`. You will then need to change your printing mechanism to use the `indent` value.

Comment: To get the file names printing correctly you need to print the file names when you see them. `if (file.isFile()){filesanddirectories.push(file.getName());` -> `if (file.isFile()){System.out.println(...`.

Comment: So print files and folders and add folders to stack?

Comment: you should print it by recursive method

Comment: Using a stack for this when you have a recursive method is somewhat unusual. Are you sure you must use a stack?

Comment: @Hans Please share your solution as an answer. I spent a significiant amount of time to find mine. So i wonder what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I used `indent` and `temp` variables to keep the indent when traversing recursively through the file directory. Then printed indent at the start of the `for` loop.

```
public static void filetree(File mainfolder, int indent) {

        int temp;

        for (File file : mainfolder.listFiles()) {
            for(int i = 0; i<indent; i++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            temp = indent;
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                indent++;
                System.out.println(file.getName()); 

                filetree(file, indent);
                indent--;

            } else if (file.isFile()) {

                System.out.println(file.getName());
                indent = temp;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of pushing things onto a stack if you're never going to pop them?

Comment: `filesanddirectories.push(file.getName());` was in OP's code, I just didn't delete the lines. Using stack has no contribution to the solution. Maybe i should update my answer.